# Trying to localize catalyst template

Tags: perl, localization, catalyst

I'm having a hell of a time trying to localize a catalyst template.  I'm using  [Catalyst::Plugin::I18N](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Catalyst-Plugin-I18N-0.10/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/I18N.pm#___top)

I have my de.po file set.

In my controller I have:

```
$c->languages( ['de'] );
$c->stash(template => 'MY_TEMPLATE.tt');
```

However, I have no idea how to call localize on this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have already set the .po file `$c->languages( ['de'] );` is not needed.
In controller :

```
$c->stash(template => 'MY_TEMPLATE.tt');
```

In template :

```
[% Catalyst.localize(text) %]
```

The text that put in localize() is the msgid text in your de.po